# How to clear the textbox using actions in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, action

I am facing an issue to clear the textbox when using actions.
Here is the code:

```
for (int j = 1; j <= TotalCount; j++) {
                //driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='fourcolumns']//div//label)[" + j + "]")).sendKeys("Test");
                WebElement CustomfieldsTextBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='fourcolumns']//div//textarea)[" + j + "]"));   
                action.moveToElement(CustomfieldsTextBox);
                action.click();
                action.sendKeys("Testing");
                action.build().perform();
            }
```

How to clear the textbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use below snippet of code,

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

actions.click(driver.findElement(element)
    .keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
    .sendKeys("a")
    .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL)
    .sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE)
    .build()
    .perform();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you need to use actions?

You can use:

```
for (int j = 1; j <= TotalCount; j++) {
     WebElement CustomfieldsTextBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='fourcolumns']//div//textarea)[" + j + "]"));   
     CustomfieldsTextBox.clear();
     CustomfieldsTextBox.sendKeys("Testing");
 }
```

Or js:

```
driver.executeScript("document.getElementByXpath('(//div[@class='fourcolumns']//div//textarea)[" + j + "]")').setAttribute('value', 'Testing')");
```

Else using actions you can try sending keys to delete the content like: select text CTRL + A and then DELETE/BACKSPACE

Comment: Actually i am using Actions because it gives "unable to focus" error. So without this it cant be resolved.

Comment: I have tried to use backspace and Control but this property is not available in actions.

Answer (score 0):

For macOS:

```
new Actions(driver)
       .click(textBox)
       .keyDown(Keys.COMMAND)
       .sendKeys("A")
       .keyUp(Keys.COMMAND)
       .sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE)
       .perform();
```